# limit of the binomial distribution

Tags: limits, statistics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

The limit of $P(x=r)$ of binomial distribution $x = B(n,p)$ where $n$ tends to infinity is zero. but what if we want to know the limit of $P(x=n/k)$ where $k>1$ and $n/k$ is rounded to the nearest integer?

For example, if $10\%$ of the population likes white chocolate but we take a survey of an unknown but very large sample and want to know what the probability that $15\%$ of the sample likes white chocolate, how would we do it?

My thoughts are that it's related to the poisson distribution but I can't work it out for myself.

Comment: Note that $n$ and n are regarded as different symbols due to the different fonts. Always make sure all mathematical symbols are formatted in MathJax.

Comment: Let $\theta = P(\text{Like white choc}) .$ Do you mean to ask if the new population has $.0145 < \theta < 0.155$ or $\theta \ge 0.15?$ There's a big difference in approach and in the result.

Comment: We could use CLT or Bayesian priors.